# Two Ubuntu Instances (Guest) networking with XP (Host) in virtual box v3.1.4

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

So here is my current objective:

1. I need to create two guest instances of Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 in VirtualBox on a WindowsXP host.  (This is needed for communications later on.)
   (this step is almost done)
2. I need to establish networking between all three OS's, the host and two guests (Guest1 -> Host -> Guest2).

I know that generally, to establish networking between Windows host and Ubuntu guest, we set up a bridge connection.  But here there are two guests, and primarily I need networking between the two guests (Ubuntu to Ubuntu).

So will there need to be a change in *tap0* and *tap1* interfaces when we set up a bridge, or is there a better way to implement this?

Please explain the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If your guests do not need direct external network access, you can use "Host-only" Network option.

Guest1 and Guest2:

```
set Adapter 1 to Bridged Adapter, eth0.
```

Comment: hi thnx for reply
bur  i  do need external network access as well on my guest os's

Comment: I'm using the *Bridged adapter* network settings on two Linux guests under VirtualBox v3.1.2 on a WindowsXP host.  My guests can access and be accessed from each other, the host, and other devices on my network; their IPs are automatically assigned from the network DHCP server.  @EnthuCrazy: if that setting isn't working for you, you may need to provide more details about your setup.

Comment: see the point is even i enable networking the aim is to setup a call session between two clients(monster or uct ims) which are registered with ims between guest ubuntu which have ims installed and xp host.
so when i installed say monster client on xp to set up a call with ubuntu guest with ims installed as i have two users registered with ims , so in monster client configuration at xp side , i need to setup configuration like .domain name.pcscf port.local portas i have already established calling in localhost of ubuntu guest between two clients registered with ims ,i need to do same xp-ubuntu